# Resetting client.pem without deleting client after a host OS re-install

Tags: chef-infra

Am running some disk intensive application which burns out disks and requires replacements and OS install frequently. However, when the host get re-installed, I want to have a post-install script that does:

- copy over the `chef.rpm` and install it
- `mkdir /etc/chef` and `/var/log/chef`
- Write out `/etc/chef/validation.pem`, `/etc/chef/client.rb` and `/etc/chef/first-boot.json`
- Run `chef-client -j /etc/first-boot.json`

However, for a host that was re-imaged I have do an out of band `knife client delete $node` on my chef workstation. Instead how can I tell the chef-server to ignore the existing `client.pem` and regenerate a new pair for the host. This would really help to remove any manual intervention every time a host gets re-imaged.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, for a host that was re-imaged I have do an out of band 'knife
>   client delete $node' on my chef workstation. Instead how can I tell
>   the chef-server to ignore the existing client.pem and regenerate a new
>   pair for the host. This would really help to remove any manual
>   intervention every time a host gets re-imaged.

Hum I may be wrong, but you obvisouly have a way/script/workflow to define a host to be created, part of this could be a call to a `knife client delete <hostname>` from the central point launching the instance.

If really needed you can handle the 'not exist' error to bypass it for new hosts which obviously don't have a client to delete.

I'll be happy to hear your blocking part on this point to better understand the problem with the knife call.

(that's just an extended version of @coderanger comment above)

Comment: I wanted to make it a closed-loop between the host and the pxeboot server. I can do that by running a post-install that executes a DELETE /clients/$hostname with some headless user's credentials. But that a wide berth for abuse if someone gets those credentials. Taken your advice and gone ahead and plugged the host cleanup into my existing workflow which opens bug/tickets etc. Thanks for the input

Comment: You're welcome. There's no easy solution there. But for security, ignoring the existing would be worse, someone with a client could fake it's node name and invalidate every host in your infra, better to keep it into the wokflow I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ignore the existing client, but you can change the client name each time. The client name defaults to match the FQDN of the machine, but you can override it via `node_name` in your client config.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, using chef-client -N <new-name> to do a nodename change after every reclone would still need an external step of cleaning up the old node_name from the chef server. Also, as I see around ~10 machines die every week (its a ~8k node cluster), renaming hosts would be an inventory nightmare (I really really like that chef gives me an inventory tool for free)

Comment: Then yeah, you'll need to remove it in a script somewhere. If you use Enterprise Chef you could use its ACL system to grant those nodes permission to delete themselves. You might also want to consider chef-solo for this kind of use case.